# Зависает принтер kyocera ecosys p2035d

Tags: windows, принтер

После обновления Windows 10 64, стал зависать принтер kyocera ecosys p2035d. Помогает только перезапуск службы печати.
В чем может быть причина?

Comment: В какой-либо несовместимости или минорной ошибке при обновлении. Попробуйте удалить принтер и драйвер печати, а затем установить заново (если имеется - то драйвер с Windows Update). Заодно посмотрите, нет ли у производителя обновления прошивки принтера.